# Arithmetic overflow expected but does not occur

Tags: rust, arithmetic-overflow

(I'm using Rust 1.44.1)

The following example fails to build (debug mode) because of arithmetic overflow (and I understand why) :

```rust
fn main() {
    let i: u8 = 255 + 1;
}
```

```
error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
2 |     let i: u8 = 255 + 1;
  |                 ^^^^^^^ attempt to add with overflow
  |
  = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default
```

While this example builds correctly :

```rust
fn main() {
    let i: u8 = 255;
    let _j: u8 = i + 1;
}
```

Since `i` is immutable, I would have expected the same error as the first example.

Am I missing something or this is something not handled by the compiler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it should be noted that warnings are emitted *on a best effort basis*.

A good policy for warnings, in general, is:

- To avoid false positives: nothing more annoying for a user than to be warned there is an issue when there is none.
- And therefore possibly have false negatives: situations that should have triggered the warning, but were not detected.

Also, due to performance considerations, analysis may be limited to the most basic patterns, which once again means that some occurrences will not be detected.

---

With that said, the warning is correctly triggered on [Rust 1.45](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9e52f7e006d0ac447d41b6575153296).

As a result, I believe you have simply hit a limitation of the 1.44.1 version.

Comment: I should have updated my Rust version before posting... Thanks for the answer !

Comment: And by the way, to be fully correct, this was not a warning but an error.

Comment: @norbjd: `arithmetic_overflow` is a warning (a lint); you may choose to _report it as an error_, using deny, but it doesn't change its nature (being a warning) and therefore the fact that it is only reported on a best effort basis.